# Node.JS Send request via web proxy

Tags: c#, node.js, proxy, web-scraping

I wrote in the past web scrape tool with C#, the scraper use tor as proxy server and send the request like that:

```
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create("http://whatismyipaddress.com/");
      request.Proxy = new WebProxy("127.0.0.1:8118");      
       using (HttpWebResponse response =    (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse()) {
                 
.....
```

This days I convert the new project to NODE.JS and I can't figure how to duplicate the same request to work.

Thanks.

Comment: Why do you wish to route your requests via Tor? Is it that your target site would wish to blog you legitimately, but you are planning to work around that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [request](https://github.com/mikeal/request) package:

```
var request = require('request');

request.get({
    uri: 'http://whatismyipaddress.com/',
    proxy: 'http://127.0.0.1:8118'
}, function (err, resp, body) {
    if (err || resp.statusCode != 200) {
        console.log('oops! something failed.');
    }
    else {
        // process body here
    }
});
```